# iterate property of NSManagedObject every time a new object is created

Tags: swift, database, xcode, core-data, nsmanagedobject

In a todolist app I am creating, I would like every new task object that is created to have a unique task id, before implementing core data I had a task class with a static instance variable that would be incremented by 1 every time a new object was instantiated. How would I do this with an NSManagedObject?

Code from non-NSManagedObject Task class

```
private static var taskID:Int = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try considering using UUIDs, *Universally Unique Identifiers*, if you want to be sure to have unique ids. These ids would be of type *string* and meet the international standards.

To generate a new UUID, anywhere you need:

```
let id : String = UUID().uuidString
```

That said, if you still want to use Integers, you can do **(deprecated)**:

```
class Task {

   static var currentTaskId : Int = 0

   var taskId : Int?

   init(){
      Task.currentTaskId += 1
      self.taskId = Task.currentTaskId
   }
}
```

That way all your instances of tasks will have a different id. However I don't recommend it because whenever you stop your application `currentTaskId` will be brought back to 0 and you will very likely have ids that are not unique anymore if your tasks are stored and reused over time.